# Can't authenticate Azure Web App with Azure AD. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

We are a teeny tiny startup. We were in Bizspark, which has now expired, but we all still have our MSDN accounts at the free level. I have commented our product code, run JsDoc3 on it to generate a documentation website. I put up a free level Web App on Azure. Works fine unauthenticated. I figured I'd throw together a small AD for the few of us in there with our Microsoft accounts, set the authentication of the app to the AD and pow, good to go. It would ask us to log in with our Microsoft accounts and all would be fine. Only we would be able to see the site with our internal code documentation. Seemed to work for me since I created everything. But everyone else I put into the AD can't authenticate. We get this error:

"AADSTS50020: User account 'joe@ourdomain.com' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'Default Directory' and cannot access the application 'app-id-key' in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account."

I have no idea. I've never used AD before. This is so common, I figure it must be the simplest use-case. I must be missing something stupid. All of my googling and searching Stack Exchange isn't finding me the answer though. Can someone please help me figure this out?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please rephrase your post (the title in particular, but also the content) as a question rather than a complaint.

Comment: Have you added the Microsoft accounts to the Azure AD in question?

Comment: Have you configured multi-tanent ?

Comment: @juunas - I only have this one web app currently, why do I need multi-tenant? Can you point me at a good blog post on it? I've seen some but they were all really complicated and seem dated.

yes. I've added the accounts already. That was one of the 1st things I did.

Comment: @juliet: [Multi-Tenant Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview) / [Multi-Tenant Sample](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-multitenant-openidconnect/)

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you have added the external account successfully in your Azure AD tenant. In my testing , if I haven’t added the external account , I will get the same error message like yours .

To add an exits Microsoft Account to azure ad tenant ,you could follow below steps :

1. In the classic portal , click **users** in your azure ad tenant .
2. Click [Add User] button ,choose type : **User with an existing Microsoft account**  :
   [image]
3. After added , you will find the added Microsoft account in azure ad tenant like :

[image]

In addition, There are some limitations of Azure AD external users ,for example ,external users can't consent to multi-tenant applications in directories outside of their home directory . You could click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-create-users-external)  to know more about external users in azure ad.